# Checking if characters in a string are digits, but with exceptions

Tags: java

Alright so I have this string ssn, and it's supposed to be a social security number with the proper format. I need to check to make sure there are no non-digits in the ssn, except for the dashes. I've already created a loop that makes sure the dashes are in the correct spot, but I'm not sure how I can make it check if there are non-digit characters without the dashes messing up the check. Is there a way I can exclude the dashes from this check?

Heres my current code, I'm just not sure how to exclude the -'s. (Sorry, completely forgot)

ssn is a string object entered by the user.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ssn.length(); i++) 
  {
     if (Character.isDigit(ssn.charAt(i)) 


}
```

Comment: use a regular expression like `^[1-9\-]$` - if theres a certain amount of dashes and/or digits per block, fix accordingly.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: @Coffee the life of the programmer in one simple comment

Comment: If you attempt this and hit a snag, come back, show your code, explain what didn't work, and then receive some suggestions.

Comment: Updated with code, had forgot.

Answer (score 1):

#### Consider using a regular expression.

For example:

```
public static boolean isValidSocialSecurityNumber(String s) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
  return m.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isSSN(String SSN){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile
        ("^[0-9]{3,3}[0-9]{2,2}[0-9]{4,4}$"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Matcher m = p.matcher(SSN);
        return m.matches();
}
```